# ember JS : iterating over a json list and displaying in handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I have a JSON object consisiting of an array of json objects.
 I want to display the  provider group List for every application as a dataList in my `JSON` object .

The JSON object is :

```
{"Application1":[{"pg_id":"test00020","pg_name":"test20","sealID":"Application1"},{"pg_id":"test00030","pg_name":"test30","sealID":"Application1"}],"Application2":[{"pg_id":"test00040","pg_name":"test40","sealID":"Application2"},{"pg_id":"test00050","pg_name":"test50","sealID":"Application2"}]}
```

I have named this JSON object as **AppPgMap**  and in my  hbs file  I am trying to access it as follows:

```
         **<input class="typeahead" type="text" id={{concat "pg_id_input"  index index_new}} list="pg_data"  onchange= {{action "getProviderGroups"   }}  placeholder="search here">  
          <datalist id="pg_data">
        <select   class="form-control " id= "new_pg_id"  oninput={{action (mut el.value) value="target.value" }}  required=true>

             {{#each AppPgMap as |application| }}
              {{#each application as |providerGroup|}}
                <option value={{ providerGroup.pg_id }}> {{providerGroup.pg_name}}</option>

                {{/each}}
             {{/each}}



       </select>  
      </datalist>**
```

This doesn't work for me and instead of getting the data list i get an empty input field .

Is there a solution to this? Or do I have to restructure my data and try displaying it another way?

Answer (score 0):

For iterating over an object you can use `each-in` [helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/)

```html
{{#each-in PgMap as |appName  appDetails| }}
  {{#each appDetails as |providerGroup|}}
    <option value={{ providerGroup.pg_id }}> {{providerGroup.pg_name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
{{/each-in}}
```